# pywinauto | Getting the tile from child_window()

Tags: pywinauto

How to get the title **CAS-31230026-RRYYM6** from the below

The print_control_identifiers() on the FormTitle returns this -

```
Control Identifiers:

Custom - ''    (L609, T259, R912, B323)
['CAS-31230026-RRYYM6Custom', 'Custom']
child_window(auto_id="FormTitle", control_type="Custom")
   | 
   | Static - 'CAS-31230026-RRYYM6'    (L613, T259, R908, B323)
   | ['CAS-31230026-RRYYM6Static', 'Static', 'CAS-31230026-RRYYM6']
   | child_window(title="CAS-31230026-RRYYM6", control_type="Text")
```

Answer (score 1):

`FormTitle.children_texts()` worked.

It cannot be done like this

```
wrapper = app.FormTitle.child_window(title="CAS-31230026-RRYYM6", control_type="Text").wrapper_object()
wrapper.window_text()
```

as the `title` is a dynamic value.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "get the title programmatically", method `.window_text()` is what you need. If you want to access other methods of the element with mentioned title, just copy and paste `child_window` line from the `print_control_identifiers()` output (BTW `dump_tree()` is an alias of this method):

```
app.FormTitle.child_window(title="CAS-31230026-RRYYM6", control_type="Text").window_text()
```

When you call `.window_text()`, the window specification is automatically used to find particular element (Python wrapper for it) which contains method `.window_text()` and it calls this method. More explicit usage:

```
wrapper = app.FormTitle.child_window(title="CAS-31230026-RRYYM6", control_type="Text").wrapper_object()
wrapper.window_text()
```

This is all described in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). Also recommend to surf for other docs (Waiting for Long Operations, Remote Execution Guide). Hope you'll find them useful.

Comment: Due to dynamic title value, I couldn't get it as suggested.  The title is the text that I wanted to capture.

Thanks for your suggestion, 

Hope you are doing well now, nearly a month of your absence had left this unanswered.

Comment: If the title is absolutely unpredictable, the `child_window()` specification has many other keywords listed here: [pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements() function](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html#pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements). Please don't use this function directly. This is just for keywords reference. For example, `parent` could be a wrapper for parent UI element which has stable title. Also `found_index` could be useful to get the first or second element of particular `control_type`.